# Completion of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ for a given norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Assume that $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a norm on the space of rapidly decaying functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Under which conditions on the norm can we say that the completion $\mathcal{X}$ for this norm is a Banach space such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{X} \subseteq  \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}),
\end{equation}
where $A \subseteq B$ means that the topological vector space $A$ is continuously embedded in the topological vector space $B$. 
This is typically valid for the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^2}$ but not for the norm $\lVert \mathrm{D} \cdot \rVert_{L^2}$, where $\mathrm{D}$ is the derivative operator.

NB. Here, the space of tempered generalized functions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ is endowed with the weak* topology.

Comment: A special case which I _think_ should be relatively easy is that of quadratic translation-invariant norms, of the form $||u||^2=\int|\hat u(\xi)|^2\rho(\xi)\ d\xi$

Comment: Did you lookup the related notions of "space of distributions" and "normal space of distributions"?

Comment: And what kind of inclusion do you want to look at? I assume you want $\mathcal{S}\subseteq X$ to be the natural inclusion into the completion. What map do you want for $X\subseteq \mathcal{S}'$ ? Usually one would look at Hilbert spaces and consider this as the dual of the other embedding while identifying $X$ with $X'$ via the scalar product. What do you want to do for a general Banach space $X$ ?

Comment: Continuing @JohannesHahn's comment, if $\mathcal S\subset X$ is continuous, _and_ if there is a natural, continuous $X\subset X'$, then the dual/adjoint of the inclusion $\mathcal S\subset X$ is $X'\subset \mathcal S'$, and splicing all these together gives the picture you want.

Comment: Is it important for you that ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$ is endowed with the ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$-weak topology? If ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$ has the topology of uniform convergence on bounded (or what is the same here, on compact) sets in  ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$ the answer seems to be simple.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The topology of $\mathcal S'$ does not really matter because of the closed graph theorem (for linear maps from Banach to LB-spaces): If $j:X\to \mathcal S'$ is $\sigma(\mathcal S',\mathcal S)$-continuous it is already $\beta(\mathcal S',\mathcal S)$-continuous (the latter topology is in fact the locally convex inductive limit topology).

Comment: Grothendieck's factorization theorem gives a *necessary* condition for the continuity of $j:X\to \mathcal S'$, namely that it factorizes over a "step" $X_n=\{u\in \mathcal S': |u(f)|\le c \sup\{(1+|x|^2)^n |f^{(\alpha)}(x)|: x\in\mathbb R^N,|\alpha|\le N\}$ for some $c\ge 0$ and all $f\in\mathcal S\}$.

Comment: @JeanDuchon, I am not so sure what happens if $\rho$ vanishes at $0$, typically in the case below.

As I said, I am especially curious about the simple norm $f \mapsto \lVert  f’ \rVert_2$. It is a norm on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, and it is not hard to see what should be the set of $\{f \in \mathcal{S}’(\mathbb{R}), \ f’ \in L^2(\mathbb{R})\}$ but do not think this space is 
the completion of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ for the norm $f \mapsto \lVert  f’ \rVert_2$.

Comment: @AbdemalekAbdesselam: I am not aware of the concept of normal space of distributions, could you point some webpage on it?

Comment: So to answer more precisely to @JohannesHahn, I am curious to know precisely when the completion of $\mathcal{S}$ for the given norm specifies a space that can naturally be seen as a (copy of) space continuously embedded in $\mathcal{S}’$. This is typically true for any norm defining a Sobolev space, but again I am not sure what happens if one consider simply the norm of the derivative.

Comment: @Goulifet: see page 7 of http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIF_1957__7__1_0

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that this is what you want, but it's too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer.

I don't see serious problems. If the conditions in terms of the theory of topological vector spaces will satisfy you, then you can consider the following. Your norm $\|\cdot\|$ must

1. be continuous on ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$ (in other words, the
   unit ball $B$ of this norm must be a neighbourhood of zero in
   ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$), and
2. generate a topology on ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$ which is
   stronger than the weak topology generated on ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb
   R})$ by the duality $$ \langle f,g\rangle=\int_{\mathbb R}f(t)\cdot
   g(t)\, d t,\quad f,g\in{\mathcal S}({\mathbb R}) $$ (in other words,
   $\forall g\in{\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})\ \sup_{f\in{\mathcal
   S}({\mathbb R}):\ \|f\|\le 1}|\langle f,g\rangle|<\infty$).

If you denote by ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})_{\|\cdot\|}$ the space ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$ endowed with the topology generated by such a norm, then you obtain a chain of continuous mappings
$$
{\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})\subseteq{\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})_{\|\cdot\|}\subseteq {\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R}),
$$
and the completion turns it into the chain 
$$
{\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})\subseteq X\to {\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R}).
$$
(since ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})_{\|\cdot\|}$ is normed, its completion consists of Cauchy sequences; on the other hand, by the [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$ is sequentially complete with respect to the ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$-weak topology, so the images of these sequences have limits in ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$).

The only detail which is not clear here is if the last mapping (the arrow $\to$) is injective. In general case [completion does not preserve injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744400/does-the-operation-of-completion-preserve-injectivity), so you should verify this in case that this is important for you.

You can also consider the strong topology on ${\mathcal S}'({\mathbb R})$ (i.e. the topology of uniform convergence on bounded or, what is the same here, on totally bounded sets in ${\mathcal S}({\mathbb R})$), where the same reasoning works also.

Comment: Your necessary requirement on $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ are interesting. Especially, the point 2. is what does not work with the norm $\lvert f' \rVert_{L^2}$, for which $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{S}, \lVert f' \rVert_{L^2}} \lvert \langle f  , g \rangle \rvert = \infty$ for most $g\in \mathcal{S}$ (as soon as the mean of $g$ is nonzero, I guess).

Comment: I should also say that the injectivity is important to me. My goal is to identify when the completion $X$ is a "valid" function space, hence I really want elements in $X$ to be distinct elements in $\mathcal{S}'$. Do you see any additional condition preserving the injectivity?

Comment: @Goulifet , it doesn't come to mind immediately, why (or when) this mapping has to be injective... Maybe I'll think a bit more, and later tell something clever on that score...

Answer (score 0):

In the general case of a normed linear space $X$ and a larger *quasi-complete* Hausdorff topological vector space $E$ (as $\mathcal S'$ is) with $X\subseteq E$ : it can be completed within $E$ iff its unit ball is closed for the topology induced on $X$ by $E$.

While this is a basic fact, I'm not sure it is present in textbooks. I found it in Laurent Schwartz's article *Sous-espaces hilbertiens d'espaces vectoriels topologiques et noyaux associés (Noyaux reproduisants)*, 1964. The proof is for quadratic norms, but is clearly valid for any norms. An interesting counter-example he gives (p.130) is the squared norm $\int \psi^2+\psi(0)^2$ for which the completion is $\{(f,\alpha):f\in L^2,\alpha\in \mathbb R\}$, not a subspace of $E=\mathcal S'$.

For (squared) norms of the special form $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\hat u(\xi)|^2|\xi|^{2s}\ d\xi$, the condition is $-\frac{d}2<s<\frac{d}2$. If $s\ge\frac{d}2$ the completion is a quotient, a Hilbert subspace of $\mathcal S'/P$ where $p\in P$ iff there is a sequence $\psi_n\to p$ (in $\mathcal S'$) s.t. $||\psi_n||\to 0$. In your case ($d=1$, $s=1$), $P$ is just the space of constant functions. (Idem in the critical case $s=\frac12$, but that's not as easy then). Your completion is the Hilbert space I would denote $D^{-1}L^2/P_0$.